# Minecraft import world problem

Tags: animation, import, world

I am doing a Minecraft Animations course and one of the things I need to do is to import a Minecraft world. I used Jmc2Obj and imported the Minecraft world into Blender. However, it ended up looking like this: [image: It's supposed to be a Mesa Biome]

It's supposed to be a mesa biome but as you can see, it looks nothing like it. I immediately identified it as a texture problem. I tried going to **file>external data>find missing files** and locating the directory that contains the "texture.png" image and the "texture.uv" file, but that didn't fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED IT! I got Mineways and exported my world using that and it worked! Here's what it looks like now: [image: What it looks like now]

Thank you for your help, [@Zophiekat](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/68753/zophiekat).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using MCprep? https://theduckcow.com/dev/blender/mcprep/ doing the "prep materials" option usually fixes most of these world problems, u do that by selecting all the objects u want to prep materials for, then click on prep on oyur left side pannel (brought up with pressing N) and thats it, a pop up will appear with an option for missing textures, try enabling that and see what happens

Comment: That just made more blank textures. Image: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b4idEKkeLNgf38aSb64KEpl-dJaz3ann/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: did u select all the world's object before doing Prep materials?

Comment: Yes. I did it by pressing A and then using prep materials.